# In maxima I want to see the numeric value of ln(3) but all it says is ln(3)

Tags: display, numeric, maxima

There are a number of situations in Maxima where I just can not persuade it to give me a numeric value, as illustrated here:

(%i12) e^1;

(%o12) e

(%i13) ln(3);

(%o13) ln(3)

I know that e^1 is e and that ln(3) is ln(3). I want to see the values as numbers.
I have searched a long time and not come close. I know that float(...) works in many cases, but not these:

(%i14) float(ln(3));

(%o14) ln(3.0)

It is exasperating. Can anyone tell me how to get a number please?
(it is Maxima 23.05.1 on Windows)

I am expecting something like

(%i15) showme(ln(3));

(%o15) 1.0986122886681096913952452369225

Comment: Jim, the natural logarithm is denoted log in Maxima. Also, bear in mind that Maxima evaluates many mathematical functions to numbers only when an exact result is possible by applying identities, *or* when arguments are inexact numbers (i.e. floats and bigfloats). E.g. log(3) => log(3), but log(3.0) => 1.0986... and also float(log(3)) => 1.0986.... Also log(exp(3)) => 3 (applying identity). If you have further questions you might try the maxima-discuss mailing list; there are more eyes on the mailing list compared to this forum. See: https://sourceforge.net/projects/maxima/lists/maxima-discuss

Comment: @president-james-k-polk You shouldn't be so quick to dismiss questions about topics, such as Maxima, which you're not familiar with.